# How to write data to a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    infoList = [] 
    count = 0

    while True:
        firstname = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        mystring = str(firstname)
        lastname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        mystring2 = str(lastname)
        telephoneno = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        mystring3 = str(telephoneno)
        contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        if contiinue == 'y':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print ("File Written")
            break

        file = open('filename', 'a');
        file.write(data.to_string());
        file.close();

 main()
```

I'm trying to get the program to write the input as a text file, but allow new information added to be added to the text file, not to erase whats already been written.

Every time I try to run the program it say that there's a problem with the main() and also a name error, as data is not defined?

Comment: your indentation is wrong for the main function, kick everything in by one tab except for the first and last line and `data` isn't defined. The first place it shows up is in your `write()` function.

Comment: Just to add for people still running python ~2.7: use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`, because `input()` internally calls `eval()` automatically.

Answer (score 3):

To add to @Clodion's answer I would use the `with` keyword

```
def main():
    infoList = [] 
    count = 0

    while True:
        fnane = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        lname = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        tele = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        ok = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        if ok == 'y':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print ("File Written")
            break

    data = fname + lname + tele
    with open('filename', 'a') as file:
        file.write(data);

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def main():
    infoList = [] 
    count = 0

    while True:
        mystring = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        mystring2 = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        mystring3 = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')
        if contiinue == 'y':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print ("File Written")
            break

        data = mystring + mystring2 + mystring3
        file = open('filename', 'a');
        file.write(data);
        file.close();

main()
```

There is a space before `main()`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_file = '/home/user/file.txt'

def add_code(my_file, permission, code):
    f = open(my_file, permission)
    f.write(code + '\n')
    f.close()

def main():
    infoList = []
    count = 0

    while True:
        mystring = input('Please enter your first name: ')
        add_code(my_file, 'a+', mystring)

        mystring2 = input('Please enter your last name: ')
        add_code(my_file, 'a+', mystring2)

        mystring3 = input('Please enter your telephone number: ')
        add_code(my_file, 'a+', mystring3)

        contiinue = input('Continue (y = yes): ')

        if contiinue == 'y':
            count = count + 1
        else:
            print ("File Written")
            break
main()
```